# $k | x^{k} - x,$ for $k, x \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: divisibility

I seem to have found that:

$$k | x^{k} - x, \ \text{for} \ k, x \in \mathbb{Z}.$$

I have tried it with a few values, and it seems to be true.

I am sure that this has been discovered before.

Comment: See [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

Comment: Ah, I have independently discovered Fermat's little theorem... xD

Comment: @DietrichBurde If you write this as an answer, I would be more than happy to accept it!

Comment: Division algebras? Really?

Comment: @MichaelGaluza Oops...

Comment: @GFauxPas I am trying to express that both $k$ and $x$ are elements of the set $\mathbb{Z}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, it does not work for all $k, x \in \mathbb{Z}$. Consider $k = 4, x = 2$: $4$ does not divide $2^4 - 2 = 16 - 2 = 14$.

However, this works if $k$ is prime, and is well-known [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

Comment: Thank you very much for a great answer!

Answer (score 1):

Your result only works for all $x$ if $k$ is a prime or a Carmichael number, and it is known as Fermat's little theorem for prime numbers.

But there are more general results known. In rewritten form, the Euler-Fermat theorem states that $$k|x^{\varphi(k)+1}-x$$
if $\gcd(x,k)=1$, and here we have $\varphi(k)$ as the Euler-phi function, equal to $k-1$ if $k$ is prime.